# How to fix: setTimeout function within a forEach function not following correct timeout

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make messages show on my site, each after 3 seconds. I'm doing this via an array (containing the messages) with a forEach function to put them in an setTimeout function, but it just show the last message after 3 seconds instead of showing all the messages each after 3 seconds.

I tried debugging, and the weird part here is that IT DOES ACTUALLY WORK IN DEBUG, just not without it.

```
const travelIntro = $text => {
  const arrMessages = ['You are travelling through empty space...', 'You wake up with only 5% oxygen left barely breathing', 'All of the sudden your ship starts up'];
  arrMessages.forEach(message => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $text.innerHTML = message;
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

So I expect it to switch between each message after 3 seconds, not just showing the last one in the array.

Comment: Well, then you have to set the first message to 3 seconds, the second to 6 seconds, the third to 9 seconds,...

Comment: I love you, I don't know how to thank you enough. How do I even select your answer as the right one?

Comment: You could also use `async`/`await` so the for loop only executes after the previous `setTimeout`.

Comment: I tried that, but that didn't work out either? I just had the exact same result.

Comment: Instead of setTimeout, you could also use setInterval to set a repeating interval of 3 seconds. Display each element one by one. Once all elements are displayed, clear the interval.

Comment: I'm going to have to check that out. @Shahzad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `setInterval`, then clear it when it returns undefined. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xukL1w0a/

```
const arrMessages = ['You are travelling through empty space...', 'You wake up with only 5% oxygen left barely breathing', 'All of the sudden your ship starts up'];

let messages = setInterval(function () {
  message = arrMessages.shift();
    if (message === undefined) {
     clearInterval(messages);
     return;
  }
  console.log(message)
},3000);
```

Comment: Thanks, spared me a lot of research on that! I will know what to use for next time now.

Comment: By the way, how do I use the clearInterval when my array is empty then?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to learn about the nature of asynchronism in Javascript

The forEach loop will actually run very fast and for each message it will immediately start a timeout. Each of the timeouts will fire 3000 ms after they have been started. So they all fire after 3000 ms, one after another.

In order for the second one to fire 3000 ms after the first one, which fired after 3000 ms you may want to establish some kind of manual loop

```
    const arrMessages = ['You are travelling through empty space...', 'You wake up with only 5% oxygen left barely breathing', 'All of the sudden your ship starts up'];

    function doLoop(i) {
       let message = arrMessages[i];
       setTimeout(function () {
          $text.innerHTML = message;
          if(i < arrMessages.length-1)
             doLoop(i+1);
       }, 3000);
    }

    doLoop(0);
```

Comment: I really do haha... My version of this fix was to add a counter that would count how many times function was executed so I could add more delay on the next ones.
`3000 + (3000 * counter)`

Comment: This is a pretty complex solution for a simple interval job.